# Is there any meaning for the path found by Hamilton's Principle to an impossible state?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, boundary-conditions

Hamilton's principle is written as a statement about the path taken between two states of the system which occur.  Is there any meaning found in solving the variational problem for points which can not occur?  For example, it is possible to solve the variational problem for an initial and final point with different total energies.  Obviously a conservative system will never gain or lose energy, so can never attain the final state, but is there any physical meaning to the path taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variational problem is not well-posed for arbitrary boundary data.  For example, consider the action

$$S[q]:= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}\left(\dot q^2 - q^2\right)$$

subject to the boundary conditions that $q(0)=1$ and $q(2\pi)=2$.  Varying this action leads to the Euler-Lagrange equation

$$\ddot q = q \implies q(t) = c_1\sin(t) + c_2\cos(t)$$

But no choice of $c_1$ and $c_2$ will actually satisfy the given boundary conditions.  Consequently, the space of trajectories which satisfy the boundary conditions does not have an extremal element.

---

The essence of the problem is that the space of solutions (in this case, trajectories through the configuration space) which are explored by variations of $q$ is restricted to those which obey the same boundary conditions as $q$ does.  We then seek an element of that space which extremizes the action, but we have *no guarantee* that such an extremal trajectory exists in that space in the first place.

In other words, the Euler-Lagrange equations are derived by **first** assuming that an extremal trajectory with the prescribed boundary data exists, and **then** working out the differential equation that it must obey - but there's no reason *a priori* to think that the initial assumption is well-founded in the first place, and in the above example it isn't.

---

> For example, it is possible to solve the variational problem for an initial and final point with different total energies.

Well, you can solve it in the sense that you can show that the solution set is empty (assuming that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=0$).  From a Hamiltonian point of view, time evolution is generated by the Hamiltonian function itself.  On-shell trajectories (which obey the Hamilton equations) are therefore guaranteed to preserve the value of the Hamiltonian function, so any trajectory which connects two states with different values for $H$ is not on-shell.

Classically, off-shell trajectories don't play a role in the sense that they do not represent physically permissible ways for the system to evolve.  In quantum mechanics this is no longer true, and off-shell trajectories contribute important information to the path integral.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider the simple case of a free classical (unlimited information) particle with a mass $m$ moving in one dimension. The state is $(x, p)$, and the Lagrangian is

$$L(t, x, p) := \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

. The Euler-Lagrange equation is then

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial p} = 0$$

which becomes, noting that $L$ has no dependence on $x$,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{p}{m} = 0$$

which is equivalent to saying that $\frac{p}{m}$ is constant. To have that, either $p$ must be constant, in which case there *is no* safe-cost path to go from $(x_i, p_i)$ to $(x_f, p_f)$ with $p_f \ne p_i$, *or* the mass $m$ must be growing in proportion to the momentum. The latter case in effect makes $L$ dependent on time $t$, so it represents a situation with a nonconservative system.

I don't have a proof, but wouldn't be surprised if it also goes this way for any other such case. It seems like it should be possible to prove it because the symmetries of the Lagrangian are what create the conservation laws per Noether's theorem, so if you are trying to ask about a situation that defies them while demanding they hold, you in effect have a contradiction and the path will fail to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hamilton's principle will never give you such an "impossible" solution.

If it seems that it does, most likely the initial or boundary conditions are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the Lagrangian has no explicit time dependence, then [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) implies that the energy is conserved on-shell, which would prohibit OP's scenario as OP already acknowledges.

   Conversely, if the Lagrangian do have explicit time dependence, it is not clear that it is actually physically inconsistent if a solution has different initial and final energies.
2. It seems OP is asking if it is consistent in the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)/[Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) as part of the boundary conditions (BCs) to specify the initial and final energy as 2 BCs? It turns out that in general it will not be consistent. Consistent BCs are typically [essential & natural BCs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127).

   Let us mention that another variational principle, [Maupertuis' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle), do keep the energy fixed, but since it is usually only formulated for conservative systems, the initial and final energies are here the same.